# I have trouble understanding this induction proof regarding generalised associativity.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a set S and a binary operation, if there is associativity among any three elements of set S, then we can infer by induction that there is associativity among any number of elements in set S.

I have been confused by this for so long, looking at many proofs and still only understanding most but not all of it. I feel like I am missing one piece of the concept in the proofs or something.

For example, in this [proof](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Associative_implies_generalized_associative), I understand everything until the last two lines where it says that (A * C) * a(n) is precisely the left-associated expression. Why is it the case that two left-associated expressions multiply to give another left-associated expression?

I am so close yet so far!

Thanks in advance. Disclaimer: I am not a math major so go easy on me.

Comment: $A * C$ has $(n-1)$ terms, i.e. less than $n$. Thus, we can apply the induction hypotheses, i.e. the assumption that the property holds for all $m < n$ that means that $A * C$ **has** (NOT: **is**) an equivalent *left-associated expression*; call it $D$. Thus, $(D) * a_n$ is the *left-associated expression* for $A * B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $(A*C)$ has $n-1$ terms, by the inductive hypothesis, we can rearrange the parentheses so that it is left-associated.

When written out, this becomes

$$((\dots(a_1*a_2)*a_3)*\dots)*a_{n-1})*a_n$$

which is the left-associated by definition.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear reply. This is what I suspected, and I wished they added this comment to make it clearer. Thanks :)